# How to transfer Olympus Master albums to a new PC?

Tags: software, olympus, file-transfer

I am migrating everything to a new Windows 7 laptop, including about 5Gb of photos. All of the photos belong to albums on the old laptop. I transferred the photos to folders with the same names on the new machine, and installed (and updated) the Olympus Master software. But I now realize that I need to transfer the information about the albums.

Is there a way to bring over the album information to the new machine, or do I need to start over and use a different approach to performing the transfer of the photos and folders?

Comment: While you can still download Olympus Master (if you first give the downloading site your email address and perhaps install a downloader program) it should be better to get the new [Olympus Viewer](http://support.olympus-imaging.com/ov2download/) software directly from Olympus site.

Answer (score 2):

According to [these](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/23389594) [forum](http://forums.techguy.org/digital-photography-imaging/893474-olympus-master-album-transfering.html) posts, you have to copy the contents of the

```
C:/Documents and Settings/Your_User_name/Application Data/OLYMPUS/Olympus_Master
```

or

```
C:/Users/Your_NAME/AppData/Local/OLYMPUS/OYMPUS_Data
```

directory.